# how to display one2many field function in xml tree view

Tags: odoo

When I want show a one2many computed field in a tree view,I got these message

ValueError: Wrong value for facturation.lot.id_articleouvrage: facturation.articleouvrage(1, 2)

```
@api.one
def get_article_list(self):
    art = self.env["facturation.articleouvrage"].search([])
    self.id_articleouvrage = art
    print self.id_articleouvrageer`

id_articleouvrage   =   fields.One2many(compute="get_article_list",relation='facturation.articleouvrage')
```

xml file:

```
<field name="id_articleouvrage">
    <tree editable="true">
    </tree>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, you need to set ids in the One2Many like this .

```
@api.one
def get_article_list(self):
    art = self.env["facturation.articleouvrage"].search([]).ids
    self.id_articleouvrage = art
    print self.id_articleouvrageer`
```

In your field One2many you specify an attribute relation. But it's only for Many2mnay field.

Doc from odoo 
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html

Comment: I set ids but i haven't any display records in my tree views

Comment: Has your error message disappeared? Did you printed value set in the field `id_articleouvrageer`? If yes could you show me the value?

Comment: the display values are :_unknown(1,2)

Answer (score 0):

One2many only works if reverse field Many2one set in facturation.articleouvrage this model.

Comment: you can give me an example please

Comment: A reverse field is not necessary when you have a computed One2many. Is only necessary if the field is store.

Comment: One2many only works if reverse field... Its nothing new.. Its pure primary key foreign key concept... Even if you put calculated you have to set reverse field otherwise it not works

Comment: @BalvantRamani Found in the code of odoo . https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/cd5f61df6d16ed377191bf43ec65ca1b01b8f034/addons/maintenance/models/maintenance.py#L369 and https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/cd5f61df6d16ed377191bf43ec65ca1b01b8f034/addons/mrp/models/mrp_bom.py#L211 before say "It not possible" try it.

Comment: @jo541 You need to check properly... https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/cd5f61df6d16ed377191bf43ec65ca1b01b8f034/addons/maintenance/models/maintenance.py#L293   there is already many2one field   maintenance_team_id = fields.Many2one('maintenance.team', string='Team', required=True, default=_get_default_team_id)

Comment: jo541,BalvantRamani please my function works,but I want it to be executed when i click on the add items button, how to do it ???? thanks

Comment: in tree view add item or have you put new custom button ?

Comment: in tree view add item

Comment: but your one2many is compute field right then why are you add manually by clicking add item ?

Comment: I used manually add item for select some items form my tree views of my field one2many